# iOS tableview with JSON objects

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my iOS app I am showing a tableview with JSON objects downloaded from an URL. Now, the tableview scrolls very slow and when showing the last rows, the images sometimes go outside the image view container looking completely messy. This is the code inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method that handles the image view inside the cell:

```
       NSMutableString *logo = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"http://not shown here"];

       NSString *imageURL = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"imagen"];
        NSLog(@"URL = %@",imageURL);


        if(imageURL != nil && ![imageURL isEqual:[NSNull null]])
        {
            [logo appendString:imageURL];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
                NSURL *logoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:logo];
                NSData *logoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:logoURL];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (logoData.length) {
                        cell.imagen_label.image = [UIImage imageWithData:logoData];
                    }else{
                        cell.imagen_label.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image.png"];
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

I need your help to improve the behaviour of the tableview.

Comment: You need to pre-fetch the images a few rows ahead. Also cache so when the user scrolls back the images are already loaded.

Comment: Thank you @Zaph, do you know a tutorial that could help me doing this?

Comment: Sorry, I have always written my own. But look for image fetching and caching code, try CocoaPods even if you don't want to use [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org). I just searched for "image cache" and got some good hits. The first hit: "FastImageCache: iOS
iOS library for quickly displaying images while scrolling" sounds like what you need, check out a number of them, many seem good.

Comment: Thank you again @Zaph , I will try CocoaPods. I hope it will help me.

Comment: @user3713806, one method to do this is override `tableView:willDisplayCellAtIndexPath`', and download a few rows ahead.

Comment: Thank you @MattSzaro, I will also take a look at your proposed method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that when the user scrolls down, the code will dispatch a dataWithContentsOfURL for each cell.  If there user scrolls far very quickly, that will queue up large numbers of downloads, even for the ones that have scrolled off the screen.

Also, with this double-dispatching the inner dispatch block will retain the cells until the image is downloaded and the inner dispatch is executed. The table could have already reused the cells for other images. If this happens, the wrong image will could be displayed.  It will be whichever finished last. (You might see it change multiple times when the scrolling stops.

There are nice examples on ways to do this in the video for WWDC 2011 session 211 
["Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?include=211#211)